# Water bogged and now I'm stranded

Tags: dodge

I just water bogged my truck and now it runs really rough. When I put it in drive it dies any ideas on what to do to get home?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what happened when you hit the water? Did the engine immediately die? Did it make any weird noises? Are the electronics working? The fact that it runs is promising, I would check the vacuum lines and intake tract for air leaks.

Comment: It died immediately and it made a lot of weird noises and backfired a lot but I pulled the air filter that was soaked and let it set for about a half hour then I restarted it and now its running better I was able to drive it to my buddies house where I'm letting the air filter dry

Comment: Good call. What's the make and model of the truck? You might have fouled a MAF sensor or something of the sort, which would definitely mess with idle performance. If it's an older truck you should also pull the dizzy cap and make it isn't a mini aquarium.

Comment: 97 dodge ram with the 5.9 engine and its idling normal now and I'm not gonna lie but I don't know what an maf sensor is or the dizzy cap

Comment: Sorry, maf stands for mass air flow, but the 5.9 has a manifold absolute pressure (map) sensor which should be fine. The dizzy is slang for distrubutor which your truck does have, but it's on the back of the engine and probably didn't get too wet. Does it still die in drive?

Comment: No after I removed the air filter and let it set for a while it ran almost perfect so I'm thinking that the soaked air filter may have been choking it I'm gonna mess with it more in the morning to see how it does hopefully no more clanking noises

Comment: Good luck, and let us know!

Answer (score 2):

If after all is dried it, the vehicle starts and runs normally, there shouldn't be an issue. Since the filter was wet and now is dry, and the vehicle is running like it should, there shouldn't be much to worry about. If it had stopped running completely and wouldn't crank, then you would have much bigger issues, such as hydrolock. Hydrolock would mean you had gotten enough water into a cylinder to have cause major damage. Since water does not compress, if you get too much into your cylinder and it will stop the engine dead, usually causing major damage when it does so.

Answer (score 2):

It runs perfectly now I guess it just needed to dry out a bit hopefully it don't happen again

Comment: You may want to replace the air filter because soaking+drying may have reduced its filtering ability.